# How to rip a DVD in codec H.265

Tags: dvd, video-conversion

Is it possible to rip a DVD in the new H.265 Codec?

I only found tools for AVC / H.264

Comment: well first, H.265 is not even out yet. Second this is something that will be in Ubuntu in the future, with that I mean like at least 4+ months (And I am really minimizing the time right there) and last please use the search tool above (that small box over at the top right, sneaky box ain't it ^^) and search for ripping, rip, dvd coding, encoding, etc.. H.265 has a long way to go before appearing on any OS as officially supported, not to mention apps like VLC, Mplayer and avconv.

Comment: surely I used the search beforehand: there was nothing with H265 so I thought, this was a good question to ask. But thanks for the info, I thought it is out, since it is already there since last year ;)

Comment: All I can give you right now is this site http://www.cnx-software.com/tag/avconv/ which you can use to test the development version of h.265.